# gsview 5.0 crashes when zoom in/out in

Tags: ghostscript, viewer

I installed Ghostscipt 9.18 and GSView 5.0 on Windows 7 Ultimate (all in 64 bits).

I had no problem to view a .ps file in GSView, but when I zoom in/out, GSView crashed, and returned "gsapi_init_with_args returns -13".

Anybody please help me out. Thanks.

Comment: I confirm this bug

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. Then I use Ghostscript 9.05 (but keeping ghostview 5.0) instead and it seems to work now. I actually downloaded form sourceforge. But I think you can download from below.

http://www.ghostscript.com/GPL_Ghostscript_9.05.html

Comment: I replaced GSView with SumantraPDF, which does the same job, and is searchable!